# Haskell : matrix sorting much slower than vector sorting

Tags: performance, sorting, haskell, matrix

I have to sort the lines of large integer matrices in Haskell and I started benchmarking with random data. I found that Haskell is 3 times slower than C++.

Because of the randomness, I expect line comparison to always terminate at the first column (which should have no duplicates). So I narrowed the matrix to a single column implemented as a Vector (Unboxed.Vector Int) and compared its sorting to a usual Vector Int.

Vector Int sorts as fast as C++ (good news !), but again, the column matrix is 3 times slower. Do you have an idea why ? Please find the code below.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as UV(Vector, fromList)
import qualified Data.Vector as V(Vector, fromList, modify)
import Criterion.Main(env, bench, nf, defaultMain)
import System.Random(randomIO)
import qualified Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro as Alg(sort)

randomVector :: Int -> IO (V.Vector Int)
randomVector count = V.fromList <$> mapM (\_ -> randomIO) [1..count]

randomVVector :: Int -> IO (V.Vector (UV.Vector Int))
randomVVector count = V.fromList <$> mapM (\_ -> do
                                               x <- randomIO
                                               return $ UV.fromList [x]) [1..count]

benchSort :: IO ()
benchSort = do
  let bVVect = env (randomVVector 300000) $ bench "sortVVector" . nf (V.modify Alg.sort)
      bVect = env (randomVector 300000) $ bench "sortVector" . nf (V.modify Alg.sort)
  defaultMain [bVect, bVVect]

main = benchSort
```

Comment: It might just be the boxing. Try it in C++ as an array of pointers to individually allocated rows rather than a multidimensional array (I'm assuming here) and compare. I don't think multidimensional vectors are supported, so if this is what's going on you'll have to do a little abstraction work to represent matrices as vectors of size n*m.

Comment: Building on @luqui, C++ multidimensional arrays are still one contiguous block in memory while here you have a vector of references to unboxed vectors. I expect you'd get considerably better performance if you used [`array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array) or [`repa`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa).

Comment: I am comparing against std::vector<std::vector<int> > in C++, so the same as Vector  (Vector Int) in Haskell, ie a vector of pointers to vectors. I thought of packing my matrix as a Vector Int of size n*m, but then I have no sort that can swap blocks of Ints at once. And even if I had that block swap, I guess it would be less efficient than sorting pointers to vectors (too many writes in memory).

Comment: The Haskell still has one extra indirection to the unboxed vectors. Edward Kmett's gotten good results by using `unsafeCoerce#` (note the `#`) to stick the pointers in directly, rather than putting in wrappers around the pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Edward Kmett as explained to me, the Haskell version has one extra layer of indirection. A `UV.Vector` looks something like

```
data Vector a = Vector !Int !Int ByteArray#
```

So each entry in your vector of vectors is actually a pointer to a record holding slice indices and a pointer to an array of bytes. This is an extra indirection that the C++ code doesn't have. The solution is to use an `ArrayArray#`, which is an array of direct pointers to byte arrays or to further `ArrayArray#`s. If you need `vector`, you'll have to figure out what to do about the slicing machinery. Another option is to switch to `primitive`, which offers simpler arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Following dfeuer's advice, implementing a vector of vectors as an `ArrayArray#` is 4 times faster than Vector (Unboxed.Vector Int) and only 40% slower than sorting a c++ `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` :

```
import Control.Monad.Primitive
import Data.Primitive.ByteArray
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.Base as GM(MVector(..))
import GHC.Prim

data MutableArrayArray s a = MutableArrayArray (MutableArrayArray# s)

instance GM.MVector MutableArrayArray ByteArray where
  {-# INLINE basicLength #-}
  basicLength (MutableArrayArray marr) = I# (sizeofMutableArrayArray# marr)

  {-# INLINE basicUnsafeRead #-}
  basicUnsafeRead (MutableArrayArray marr) (I# i) = primitive $ \s -> case readByteArrayArray# marr i s of
    (# s1, bar #) -> (# s1, ByteArray bar #)

  {-# INLINE basicUnsafeWrite #-}
  basicUnsafeWrite (MutableArrayArray marr) (I# i) (ByteArray bar) = primitive $ \s ->
    (# writeByteArrayArray# marr i bar s, () #)
```

For example, sorting a matrix of integers will then use

```
sortIntArrays :: ByteArray -> ByteArray -> Ordering
sortIntArrays x y = let h1 = indexByteArray x 0 :: Int
                        h2 = indexByteArray y 0 :: Int in
                    compare h1 h2
```